Pinewood Derby Physics
Consider the case of a water rocket toy of the type where an old PET soft drink bottle is first filled with water and then pressurized with air. The driving air pressure remains relatively constant as it only expands over a small volume.
These toys are often used to demonstrate the rocket equation and other principles of physics.
But what is the best way to model the parameters of something like a $\mathrm{CO_2}$ rocket?
What is the most straightforward way to determine exhaust velocity, mass flow rates, etc.? Where both parameters are constantly changing and interdependent?

The water bottle rocket is a simple reaction device but it can be analysed with varying levels of fidelity.
The rocket can be approximated as a cylinder with a tiny hole at the bottom. The top is filled with pressurized air, the bottom has some liquid (usually water). The liquid is our main propellant.
Basic Analysis

We simplify the bottle rocket and assume ideal inviscid (without viscosity) and steady (doesn't depend on time) flow conditions. This allows the usage of Bernoulli's equation.
$P_{air} + \dfrac{1}{2}\rho_{air} v^2 + \rho_{air} gh = P_{atmos} + \dfrac{1}{2}\rho_{water} v^2 + \rho_{water} gh$
The LHS can be simplified as the air's velocity is insignificant and the potential energy change in the short bottle is negligible on both sides.
$P_{air}= P_{atmos} + \dfrac{1}{2}\rho_{water} v^2$
which can be rearranged to,
$v = \sqrt{\dfrac{2(P_{air} - P_{atmos})}{\rho_{water}}}$
We assume that the bottle expends its propellant instantaneously and that allows us to get an impulsive force acting upwards on the rocket, which is:
$F = m_{w}v - mg$
$mg$ is the weight of the whole rocket, including the water, just before launch. $m_{w}$ is the weight of all the water in the rocket. If you assume, at time = 0, that the empty bottle was accelerated upwards with a force as we calculated above, you should have a rudimentary analysis of a bottle rocket.
This analysis is obviously not complete as the radius of the bottle opening, the expansion of the gas in the bottle and all the time dependent behaviour is not accounted for.
A Better Analysis
Consider using the adiabatic expansion relation $P(t) = P_0 (\dfrac{V_0}{V(t)})^\gamma$ where $P_0$, $V_0$, $P(t)$, $V(t)$ and $\gamma$ are initial pressure, initial volume, pressure as a function of time, volume as a function of time, and the ratio of specific heats respectively. The pressure values change based on the changing volume of air in the bottle, which depends on the mass flow rate of water from the bottle. Simply using $\rho \pi r^2 v$ as the mass flow rate ($v$ is water velocity calculated for each step in time using the previous method) should be sufficient to update $V(t)$ in a stepwise calculation (using excel or some programming language).
Although more sophisticated, this method is still rudimentary. If you really want the best possible way to analyse water bottle rockets, I would recommend this paper by Cedric J. Gommes.
$CO_2$ Rockets
A pressure driven cold gas rocket is probably more simple than the bottle rocket. The wiki article on it has the formula to calculate the thrust output of one.
$ F=A_tP_c\gamma \left [ \left (\frac{2}{\gamma - 1}\right ) \left( \frac{2}{\gamma + 1} \right) \left (1 - \frac{P_e}{P_c} \right) \right ] + P_eA_e $
Where $A_t$ is the area of the throat, $P_c$ is the chamber pressure in the nozzle, $\gamma$ is the specific heat ratio, $P_e$ is the exit pressure of the propellant, and $A_e$ is the exit area of the nozzle.
Typically mass flow rate is chosen before a rocket is designed. For those $CO_2$ cartridges you may be talking about, the mass flow rate and exhaust velocity can be estimated using the same method as the one applied to the water bottle rocket (you just need the pressure of $CO_2$ and the radius of the opening).
